# Why is terraform creating a resource not included with --target argument?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I often need to run Terraform on a few resources only, while ignoring other parts of its plan. There's a feature for that, the `--target` argument. However, quite often, when I use it, some resources that were not included with the `--target` argument still appear.

For example, I targeted resources of a remote_execute in my `apply` command, but terraform also included the creation of some NICs and VMs that are missing. Those are a part of the definition, but I just don't want (and can't) create them right now.

Why (and how) do they "sneak in" to the plan? And is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: No, there is no way to prevent it ***if*** the actually targeted resource has *some* kind of dependency (direct or transitive) on those resources. If there are no such dependencies those resources should not be part of the terraform plan. Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: it doesn't (at least is shouldn't have) - in my example I want to run a remote exec on a machine with the index 43, but the resource that it creates are NICs and VMs with an index of 0 and 10. So no (obvious) dependency there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-target` argument instructs Terraform to include the specified objects *and anything they depend on*, because otherwise this would violate the dependency relationship.

This includes both explicit dependencies written with `depends_on`, implicit dependencies given by just referring to another object, and also some special sorts of dependencies that Terraform generates for itself such as the dependency between a resource and its associated provider configuration.